# R : How to assign data points to a bin as a list ? Getting error- zero replacement length and warning - not a multiple of replacememt length

Tags: r, list, bin

Please help me in figuring out what is going wrong in the following code.

```
library(rlist)
table<-list()
bin_indices<-c(3,3,1,3,3,2,3,1,1,3)
data_indices<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)

for(data_index in seq_along(bin_indices)){
        bin_index<-bin_indices[data_index]

        if(!(bin_index%in%table)){
        #If no list yet exists,assign the bin an empty list.
                table[bin_index]<-list()

        }

       table[bin_index]<-list.append(table[bin_index],data_index) 

        }
```

When I run the above code I get the following error

```
   Error in table[bin_index] <- list() : replacement has length zero
   In addition: Warning message:
   In table[bin_index] <- list.append(table[bin_index], data_index) :
   number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Basically I am trying to assign the data_indices to the corresponding bin indices. There are 3 different bin_indices namely 1,2 and 3 and 10 data indices having values 1 to 10.
As an end result I want

```
data indices 3,8,9 assigned to table[1] as a list
data indices 6     assigned to table[2] as a list
data indices 1,2,4,5,7,10 assigned to table[3] as a list
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you want us to tell you what is wrong with your code, or do you want code to achieve the desired result, or both, or neither?

Comment: @ngm it is both. you have already provided hints on how to achieve desired results. thanks so much. if you could also let me know what is wrong with the code that will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use this code to accomplish what I think you want:

```
bin_indices<-c(3,3,1,3,3,2,3,1,1,3)
data_indices<-c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)

lapply(sort(unique(bin_indices)), function(x) data_indices[which(bin_indices==x)])
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 3 8 9
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 6
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1]  1  2  4  5  7 10
```

Although possibly you want a list of lists, and not a list of vectors. If you want a list of lists use `as.list(data_indices[which(bin_indices==x)])` inside this code.

The problem with your code is essentially that you are thinking in some other language and trying to literally translate into `R`. It is hard to know where to start with suggestions. The crux of the problem is a misunderstanding of what `%in%` does.

Run this code and study and understand the results:

```
foo <- list(1:2, 1:4)
bar <- list(1:2)
baz <- 1:2
qux <- 1

qux %in% baz
qux %in% bar
qux %in% foo
baz %in% bar
baz %in% foo
bar %in% foo
foo %in% foo
```

In my opinion it's unusual to use `%in%` with lists. It's mainly used with atomic vectors (i.e. vectors of constants like `c(1,2,3)` or `c("a","b",c")`).

Comment: thanks. can i use `is.element()`instead of `%in%` with lists. you are absolutely right - in fact I was trying to convert a Python implementation of LSH algorithm to R.

Comment: `is.element` and `%in%` are identical implementations of `match(x, y, 0) > 0`. You can review the manual for each to see.